# Ubuntu 18.04 micro sd card locked readonly

Tags: sd-card, read-only

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 on one desktop, and Windows 10 (19 something the latest version), on an old Dell Vostro-220 on another desktop. The mission is to flash an android OS onto a micro SD card for use in a Raspberry Pi 3B.

The SD card is a Samsung 32 Evo+ that has the Raspbian Stretch OS on it and the Pi works fine. I powered off the Pi and removed the Samsung SD card. I had the downloaded Android OS in a folder in my Dowloads directory. I plugged the card into an adapter (that has **NO** readolny switch), into the Ubuntu desktop. The card is found and the files are readable.

I am using Etcher to flash the OS onto the SD card. Etcher shows the card as "Locked". The card is locked in a readonly state

I can not remove the folders, format, delete the partition, or write to the micro SD card. I tried:

- gparted
- disks
- parted
- guidus
- dd commands
- Changing permissions and ownership
- disk manager in Windows
- diskpart in Windows
- formatting in my Samsung Galaxy phone
- maybe a few more "fixes" I can't remember

Nothing has worked. I have created a ticket at Samsung but there is no one in customer service today, Saturday. Then I tried another used 32 gig micro SD card that I had taken out of an old phone. I got the same result. I thought maybe because it was formatted in a phone that it was locked in readonly.

So I plugged in a brand new micro SD card. I opened Etcher to flash the Android OS to the brand new, never used, just out of the package, micro SD card, that has no switch, and got the same result. Etcher says the SD card is locked. It is in "readonly". Nothing I have tried can make it writable. Three different cards, three different brands, 1 new, 2 used (but working fine before), I plugged them into the 18.04 desktop.

I have spent several hours searching for a solution, and tried many things. Has anyone actually solved this problem? Please advise.

After dmesg  I get this:

```
[11509.378299] usb-storage 3-6:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[11509.380121] scsi host6: usb-storage 3-6:1.0
[11510.405142] scsi 6:0:0:0: Direct-Access     MXT-USB  Storage Device   
1109 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0 CCS
[11510.405965] sd 6:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
[11510.406583] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] 60751872 512-byte logical blocks: 
(31.1 GB/29.0 GiB)
[11510.406712] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is on
[11510.406716] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 03 00 80 00
[11510.406843] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] No Caching mode page found
[11510.406849] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[11510.409688]  sdc: sdc1
[11510.411556] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable dis
```

In the last day or so, I have tried a few more would-be solutions including a registry edit, and software in Windows, as well as would-be fixes in the command line. And again pardon my lack of knowledge, and this may be of topic because it's not a "Ubuntu" issue. However the only common denominator with the 3 micro SD cards is they were in the desktop running Ubuntu. One was functioning in a Raspberry PI. One was functioning in a Samsung Galaxy phone, And one was brand new out of the package.

The micro SD card that was in the phone still functions in the phone. I used the format function in the phone. It wiped out the data and installed Android files. And it writes picture and video files, I can copy the files on my desktop. So the card is not a total loss. The micro SD card that was in the Raspberry Pi is also still functioning. I just ran an update & upgrade. A lot of packages were upgraded, so the Pi is writing new data on the card.

So at this point I'm just out the new micro SD card. I suppose it will work in the phone. And I will try to get some solution from the manufacturer. I will report back if a solution is found, and to see if anyone here has any thing to say.

The manufacturer of one of the micro SD cards in question here is Samsung. It is the one I use in my Samsung Galaxy phone. I had gone on the website and created a customer service ticket number. I called the customer service line and got through to a human. I gave her the ticket number. She did her best to find a solution, after several minutes she had another representative take my info so I could get a replacement micro SD card. I was satisfied with that solution. I would have to send in my SD card (along with a receipt). Even though I could format the SD card in the phone, essentially wiping the data,  I asked if I could not wipe out the data on the SD card, Samsung would have what ever was on the SD card, yes? The rep said I could cut the SD card in half with a pair of scissors and send in both halves.

Since the micro SD card functions fine inside of the phone, I'll just keep it in there. I will not plug in another SD card into my main desktop. This may not be a "Ubuntu issue" However, this issue is not solved.

The End

Comment: When you `mount` it, look at the messages as to why it's read-only (if it gets mounted read only).   The messages will be clear & what I'd look at, however most of your post was off-topic having nothing at all to do with Ubuntu. https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic

Comment: I apologize if this is not related to the Ubuntu OS. I think it is caused by my computer.

Comment: I don't get any message when I plug in a SD card. It shows up under the Trash directory above the Other Locations directory. It's brand new so when I click on it, it is empty as expected. When I go to the properties/ permissions, it shows Owner ME, Access Create and delete files. But I am unable to put anything on this SD card.

Comment: Did you look in messages?  eg. I just mounted a thumb-drive in order to write a daily ISO to it, `dmesg` gives me details of the mounted device, I won't `mount` mine (`dd` is writing the ISO to it currently), but if you `mount` yours I'd expect the reason to be evident (as to it being read-only)

Comment: additional note: you may have to look in `journalctl` to see messages for `mount`

Comment: I apologize for my lack of knowledge. The SD card mounts as soon as I plug it in. I ran the command "dmesg"  in the terminal and put the result in the post. I see "Write Protect is on". How can I turn off write protection?